# Difference between Range.include? and Range.member? in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby has a very useful `Range` class for expressing alphabetical and numerical ranges.

There are two methods on this class that I can't seem to distinguish between:
`Range.include?` and `Range.member?`

[Ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html) gives exactly the same description for both.

What are the differences between them, if any?

Comment: If you click on the "show source" in the documentation, the source is identical. So I expect that they are synonyms (aliases).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are aliases of each other. If you expand the source code in the docs you see they both refer to the same internal function.

Answer (score 3):

```
Range.instance_method(:include?) == Range.instance_method(:member?)
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click to "toggle source" to see that their code is the same.

After that, you can go to [ruby github repo](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1aa54bebaf274bc08e72f9ad3854c7ad592c344a/range.c#L1136) to see that those methods are the same.